# PageSpeed Insights doesn't recognize WebP. format

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, webp, pagespeed-insights

I have a plugin that converts all the images that in my website to a WebP. next-gen format.
After a simple check, I can see that the images are converted.
[the check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pncty.png)

But the only problem is that PageSpeed Insights still giving me the same message that I should convert to next-gen format. 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsuper-zava.co.il%2F%25D7%25A6%25D7%2591%25D7%2599%25D7%25A2%25D7%25AA-%25D7%2593%25D7%2599%25D7%25A8%25D7%2594

Where is the problem?

Comment: WebP not supported by IOS safari browser so Instead of changing images to webp try to optimize and scale it properly. I don't know why google asking for it as Apple does not support webp.

Answer (score 0):

It still looks like a .png: http://prntscr.com/no7o9i
Try right click + save image and double check.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have changed something in the meantime, but it is now delivered properly:

[Google Chrome Dev Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnpJ3.png)

[Internet Explorer Dev Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXvcE.png)
(*somewhat odd; see content-encoding delivered as gzip?*)

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42067885/google-page-speed-insight-does-not-support-webp-images/57724799)

You can find complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57724799/5642493)

> **TL;DR** This might be the issue of user-agent(UA), If in any way you are
>   using UA to detect webp compatible browser at your server. If so, then include UA of
>   lighthouse (**Chrome-Lighthouse**) as well in your image server